# Can't perform simple array search from array

Tags: php, html, arrays, search

I have a program that is failing because it's not finding the `$post` in the search of the array, so it's continuing to add each time.  I have used the other suggested method of using a `foreach` loop, with `strpos`, such as:
`if (strpos($data, $posts) !== false)`, and this will work find the `$post`, but it will also find the rest and run against everything in the data/array.  hence why I would just like it to search the array, if it's not there add it, if it is, just say it's there or checking in...  I've spent 3 days using `in_array`, `array_search`, etc, now I'm asking for help...

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
$post = $_POST['name'];
$data = file("data.txt");
if (in_array($post, $data)) {
    echo "$post is checking in...";
}
else {
    echo "Adding to $data...";
    $data = fopen("data.txt", "a+");
    fwrite($data, $post.PHP_EOL);
    fclose($data);
}
$data = file("data.txt");
foreach ($data as $d) {
    echo $d;
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

tclient.html

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="test4.php" method="POST">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

data.txt

```
Names
John
Doe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in `$post` probably doesn't have a new line at the end. You can specify not to include new lines when you use [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php).

```
file("data.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Comment: Interesting that you have to flag for this behavior.  It would quite sensibly be the default behavior.

Comment: @JuanTomas Agree to agree.

Comment: Lol, 3 days, something that was answered in 3 mins, lol.  Can you tell I'm a noob?

Comment: Nah, it happens. I only know about it because I went through the same thing. I think most people would look for the solution to that problem in the wrong place initially because it doesn't seem like that's what `file` should do.

Comment: It's working now, so long as there is something in the data.txt file.  It can be the correct name value in the txt file, it will not catch it the first time, but the 2nd time I send the post, it will.  So if I have the data.txt file with name of Thomas in it.  It will not find it on the first attempt (although it's in there) and it's out put is:                                                                      Adding to Array...
Currently Monitoring:
ThomasThomas

Comment: If I run it again, it still doesn't find it:  Adding to Array...
Currently Monitoring:
ThomasThomas
Thomas

Comment: 3rd time it works, and it starts to show the else statement.  But if I run the same thing without anything in the data file, it'll keep adding and never stop...

Comment: Well, it looks like all I needed to do was change from using array_search, to in_array, and all works now.  Thanks!!!